# Jstree 3.2.1 not highlighting selected nodes

Tags: jstree

I just want to find out is the Plugin["ui"] still usable in jstree 3.2.1 because at the moment it not highlighting anything on my tree the only way I can get my selected nodes highlighted is by using "keep_selected_style": true but thats not what I want because now it highlights every when able to select multiple nodes.

Any idea's or help ?

Comment: What is highlighting? You can select multiple nodes out of the box with no plugins just holding a ctrl button.

Comment: @NikolayErmakov What I mean by highlighting when I have selected the node that it should show that it is selected by giving it a darker color.

Comment: In this fiddle [https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/7bax2L5o/](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/7bax2L5o/) you can click a node and get it highlighted with blue color. If you hold ctrl button when clicking a node you can have multiple selections. Is this really your question?

Comment: @NikolayErmakov not sound stupid that is what I wanted. But from your fiddle I just played around and added "checkbox" in the plugin then the whole thing works completely different because now each node can be selected. And the way my tree works are with checkboxes and that is how I get my node id. I did update your fiddle. just keep in mind that I don't hardcode my tree into the core I use a database I get all my information from the server side and then I send it to the core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want checkboxes to behave this way: 1) click on any non-selected checkbox node removes previous selection and sets new selection to the current checkbox node, and 2) to be able to select multiple checkboxes only holding `ctrl` button - you can add some code to your `select_node` event like this:

```
    var selectedNodeId = data.node.id,
        ctrlKeyPressed = data.event.originalEvent.ctrlKey,
        currentlySelectedNodes = [];

      if( !ctrlKeyPressed ){ 
        // deselect all selected except current
        currentlySelectedNodeIds = $('#tree').jstree().get_selected();
        for(var i=0, len=currentlySelectedNodeIds.length;i<len;i++){
                if (currentlySelectedNodeIds[i] !== selectedNodeId) {
                    $('#tree').jstree().deselect_node( currentlySelectedNodeIds[i] );
            }
        }
      }
```

Check [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/7bax2L5o/4/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Nikolay I appreciate your help. = )